# How to show Bootstrap 3 popover when page is loaded and then hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a question regarding to Bootstrap 3. I want to show popover, when the page is loaded -> when client opens certain html page, popover shows up and then after some time that popover fades out. What is the best way to do this? I am trying this where `.poper` is just a div's class around image

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $(".poper").popover('show');
    $(".poper").hide(600);
});
```

Thank You for Your replies.

Answer (score 7):

If I get you right, you want to show the popover if the page if *fully* loaded, so the page is ready.

If so, a possible solution could be to set a timeout in the script, which calls the popover to close.
This could look like this:

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('.poper').popover('show');
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('.poper').popover('hide');
    }, 600); //600 are the ms until the timeout is called
});
```

**Explanation:** The script show until the page is fully loaded the popover `.poper` and starts a timeout which will it closes it after 600ms.

Comment: Thank You very much! :) It simply WORKS

Comment: @user859670 You're welcome. And please accept the answer so that others can see that it is solved ;)